# Position bars between tick marks (and not on tick marks) in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am using Plotly and Python to chart a bar plot. On the x-axis, Plotly arranges the values from each trace around the centre of the tick mark.

This is what I am getting now:

[image]

I would like to have the data points (and labels) in between the tick marks. In the example chart, this would mean all the bars centered around 0-2kw would move left of the first tick and the label centered, all the bars around 2-4kw would move between the first and second ticks and the label centered, etc..

I am using tickmode=array, ticktext as an array and also set tickson=boundaries, but it's still the same.

Is there a way to do this?

(Not sure if this makes any difference but there are multiple charts in subplots)

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

Normally setting *tickon=boundaries* should do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work in conjunction with *tickmode=array* and *ticktext*.

The solution for me was to create the labels array and provide it to the bar chart as the x parameter, something similar to this:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(name='Trace1', x=['0-2kw', '2-4kw', '4-6kw', '6-8kw'], y=[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4]))
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, tickson='boundaries')
```

Doing this in my code now the data bars are in between the grid lines:

[image]